# WinApi Get Window Handle of item of ComboBox

Tags: winapi, mfc, combobox, ccombobox

I am trying to draw something on the Items of CComboBox in WinApi.
To do this I need a handle of the window which represents the item(which contains particular item).
I have a question is this possible?
How can I do it?
Or mayby have you got another idea how to draw on particular items of ComboBox.
Przemek

Comment: +1 because you also mention what you're trying to accomplish (drawing items of the combobox yourself)

Comment: Dont know the MFC way, but in plain Win32 you use CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO message to get the handle for list window and edit control. And yeah, use owner draw to draw the items manually.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an **ownerdrawn** combobox.

Refer [CCombobox::DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5hb5f9t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) documentation to know how to get the handle of each item when it is to be drawn and how to draw it.

> The framework calls this member function for the owner of an
>   owner-draw combo-box control, list-box control when a visual aspect of
>   the control has changed

Note: You must specify the style `CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` while creating the combo box. (You can also set it from the properties window of the combo box in visual studio resource editor.)

Comment: thanks a lot probably it is what i was looking for. If i will have a problems with application i will post about it here. thanks man

Comment: OK thank you  i have got another question related to previous.
I have got something like
void CCustomComboBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct){
        HDC memory;
        LineTo(memory,10,10);
        ........
 HDC hdc=::GetDC(lpDrawItemStruct->hwndItem);
   
        .....
        BitBlt(hdc,0,0,20,20,memory,0,0,SRCCOPY);

}
It doesn't copy memory to hdc
Does anybody know why?
Przemek

Comment: @PrzemyslawWisniewski you must do `memory = ::CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );` to create the device context compatible with your control item's device context.

Comment: i also tried it and i produced:                                                         void CCustomComboBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct){
 HDC hdc=lpDrawItemStruct->hDC;
 RECT r=lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;
 HDC memory=::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
 LineTo(memory,10,10);
 BitBlt(hdc,0,0,20,20,memory,0,0,SRCCOPY);

};     but it still doesn't work

Comment: @PrzemyslawWisniewski Also, you can use lpDrawItemStruct->hDC and use it directly to draw your line instead of using memory dc. Refer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229/Color-Picker-Combo-Box

Comment: You're right. FillRect() was an issue. Next and probably last question is if can I draw on HDC first , without knowing of original HDC , so i can't use CreateCompatibleDC().

Comment: @PrzemyslawWisniewski i didn't get you. what do you meant by original HDC? You can draw directly using the hdc of the item instead of using memory dc so that you don't need to use CreateCompatibleDC().

Comment: Yes but: the issue is that i would like to give as an argument to a function what to draw. F.e something like MyDrawItem(CDC*) and this function will copy and argument to a CDC pointed by hDC member of structure LPITEMDRAWSTRUCT in OnDrawItem method.

Comment: @PrzemyslawWisniewski what exactly are you trying to draw, is it just a line or a bitmap? if bitmap, you can pass the handle to it instead of device context to a function and do the drawing from that function. I'm not sure whether its a good approach passing the memory dc to another function for drawing.

Comment: i should draw anything i want. this mean that an argument should be CDC*. it would be good approach if i could get original CDC to call, because i would use then BitBlt function. i hope you know what i mean. i think there are two strategies: get the HDC which is passed in OnDrawItem, before call this function. But i don't know how to get it. Second is to Create abstract CDC, draw on it and then pass it to the function, and Copy it from this abstract CDC to the original CDC from OnDrawItem method.

Comment: @PrzemyslawWisniewski Create a CDC* object. and then use the funciton `CDC::Attach` to attach the `lpDrawItemStruct->hDC` to your CDC object and pass it to the function that draws.

Comment: yes i thought about it and i suppose it would be very good solution but: i don't know lpDrawItemStruct->hDC before call InsertString()  for example.

Comment: @PrzemyslawWisniewski It doesn't work that way. you need to draw everything at DrawItem function itself or from a function called from it. Go through the references I shared to get a clear idea.

Comment: hmm thanks for advices but i still haven't got an idea how to solve it, because as i mentioned : all the drawing operation will be called before DrawItem method. because i would like to create a method like DrawItem(CDC*) . mayby have you got another idea? anyway thank you very much

Comment: after minutes of rest i came up with an idea of callback function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the CComboBox you have to inherit from the `CComboBox` class and override the functions `OnCtlColor`. Look into [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/45d6426c-eac4-45c8-b5b0-d85005c72c23)

Comment: It gives me the handle to the whole ComboBox. I would like to draw on a particular item of it instead. Mayby your approach is good but then i would have to do  an additional job to draw only in a rect of item. Przemek

Comment: @PrzemyslawWisniewski: After reading your question i thought what you need is how to get a handle of a combobox. I will update my answer